# spiciness level / difficulty level icons?

Tags: graphics

I would like to specify difficulty level for an exercise as a number of chilli peppers next to each other, where X out of 5 are red and the rest are just outlined, so that denotes difficulty level X.

Is there some way to do it in latex, perhaps using unicode characters or otherwise?

(Something like that: https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/65/08/97/240_F_265089793_47NcOlF3q1YqH76GVC0o9wFTXIh8yKjs.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

[`fontawesome5`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5) has a chili pepper symbol. As suggested by @Robert in the comments, an empty version of the same symbol is easy to do with the `contour` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\newcommand*{\fullchili}{\textcolor{red}{\faPepperHot}}
\newcommand*{\emptychili}{\textcolor{white}{\contour{red}{\faPepperHot}}}
\begin{document}
\fullchili
\emptychili
\end{document}
```

Comment: for the empty chili you could use the `contour` package: `\textcolor{white}{\contour{red}{\faPepperHot}}` (Make sure to load it with option `outline`.)

Comment: @Robert Wow this works great! Thanks, I did not know this package.